# Updating default html checkbox styles?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am facing a problem I am trying to figure out how can I update my html checkbox in such a way that once it is checked instead of tick ✔️ inside I place a small white squared div with lesser dimensions as shown in the attached picture. when I un-check it is just a normal black background checkbox with white-border.

[image]

I placed some effort here but was out of luck, unfortunately.

```css
.checkbox-container input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.checkbox-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkmark {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
  Checkbox
```

Comment: Hi, could you please post your code in a snippet instead of linking to an external source?

Answer (score 4):

This should work if your only goal is to have a white box inside, This works by using both a `border` and an `outline`

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

input {
  appearance: none;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  outline: solid 2px white;
}

input:checked {
  border: solid 4px black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: please put this in a code snippet

Comment: @Apodemus Thanks for reminding me! Should be in a snippet now.

Answer (score -1):

Upon some research into this, using the pure html 'checkbox' this is impossible due to CSS not giving enough flexibility into this specific area.
However this would certainly be possible if you were to re-create the check box functionality by yourself, I'll try and work on a little base for how this might look:

```
<div class="checkbox"> <!-- Style this div to be a white square with a grey outline like the checkbox is normally -->
    <img class="check" src=" image source here ">
</div>
```

Then if you need to check if the div is checked or not then you can just test if the checkbox has an img source as a child or not.